# How to implement swipe in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, hammer.js

I am making a game for mobile devices with Phaser 3. I am stuck at implementing swipe mechanism. I want to swipe my character in any direction the user wants to. I also thought about doing it with hammer.js but couldn't incorporate it with Phaser. If you can integrate hammer.js with Phaser please enlighten me. I found some tuts online.

[GameDev forum](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/39661-creating-swiping-mechanism/&ved=2ahUKEwiP2JLs4OHhAhXObn0KHTs0DUYQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0jtAGU-pJYvb8hmj6hHhSM)

[Touch events](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/touchevents/)

[Sokoban game](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2018/02/09/phaser-3-version-of-the-html5-swipe-controlled-sokoban-game/&ved=2ahUKEwiP2JLs4OHhAhXObn0KHTs0DUYQFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3mj3xUL6fNjBtnGSmcREEz)

[Hammer.js and Phaser](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/36008-mobile-tutorials-or-examples/)

[2048 with Phaser](https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2018/03/21/html5-2048-game-made-with-phaser-3-updated-adding-spritesheets-and-swipe-control/)

[Phaser labs](http://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=input/&q=)

Comment: On pointer down save X/Y coordinates, on release check `current X/Y - saved X/Y`, move character (maybe add velocity) based on delta.

Comment: You should use tweens for that and swipe your sprite with inputs handlers because sure that you can add HammerJS as Phaser is a framework that uses a canvas to display its Game Objects, but you can try to play with HammerJS for example with a global variable and see what happens, sorry I don't have an example right now to let you see that

Comment: If you want something light, you can get all the information you need from the pointer in the pointer up event. https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.Pointer.html